How do I fetch a blob (WKB) type field from DuckDB using jOOQ?
I have a a few columns across different tables that store geometries in WKB (which in general terms is a blob type) format. When I use jOOQ to fetch such a column, the column is fetched as null and hence it throws an exception as below:
Error while reading field: "LOCATION"."GEOM", at JDBC index: 7

    at org.jooq_3.19.10.DUCKDB.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq_3.19.10.DUCKDB.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3607)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3595)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:827)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:1405)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.hasNext(CursorImpl.java:1366)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:174)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractCursor.fetch(AbstractCursor.java:177)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractCursor.fetch(AbstractCursor.java:88)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:265)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:348)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:290)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:3232)
    at org.n52.sta.data.cloudnative.dao.impl.AbstractStaEntityDao.findAll(AbstractStaEntityDao.java:186)
    at org.n52.sta.data.cloudnative.dao.impl.LocationDaoImpl.findAllByThingId(LocationDaoImpl.java:66)
    at org.n52.sta.data.cloudnative.test.dao.LocationDaoTest.testWithFindAllByThingId(LocationDaoTest.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while reading field: "LOCATION"."GEOM", at JDBC index: 7
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1592)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorRecordInitialiser.apply(CursorImpl.java:1518)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorRecordInitialiser.apply(CursorImpl.java:1433)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:144)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:1390)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:798)
    at org.duckdb.DuckDBResultSet$DuckDBBlobResult.getBytes(DuckDBResultSet.java:446)
    at org.jooq.impl.BlobBinding.get(BlobBinding.java:151)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultBytesBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:2306)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultBytesBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:2155)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$InternalBinding.get(DefaultBinding.java:1129)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1582)
    ... 80 more

I am not sure but it seems like an issue with the underlying DuckDB JDBC driver? I don't think I am doing anything wrong in my code.
As a workaround, I am wrapping the field in ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromWKB(LOCATION.GEOM)) function to be able to atleast fetch the value, but because I have autogenerated record classes from a DDL script that defines the column as a blob type, the RecordMapper fails to fetch the text version of the field and returns a null for the same. Though I can handle this by another workaround of avoiding to map the record into the Autogenerated record class, but I don't think of it as a neat solution

DuckDB spatial support will ship with jOOQ 3.20.0:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12736

Prior to that release, you're on your own. 3.20.0-SNAPSHOT builds are available from here though:

https://www.jooq.org/download/versions


Thank you for your response. I understand that spatial support is limited with 3.19, but why is jOOQ not able to fetch DuckDBBlobResult type? That seems to be a general type and not dependent on spatial support

@HumaidKidwai: It looks like a bug in the duckdb_jdbc driver. Try removing jOOQ in a more minimal reproducer using JDBC only, and report it here: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb-java
